# Is there any way to set a custom Order status for partial refunded order?

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to automatically update my WooCommerce order status to wc-partialRefunded when the order refunded partially.

I have successfully created the custom order status and not sure how to count the order quantity and get the result.

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried below code to create the custom order status:-

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 'register_custom_order_status' );

function register_custom_order_status( $order_statuses ){

   // Status must start with "wc-"
   $order_statuses['wc-partialRefunded'] = array(                                 
   'label'                     => _x( 'Partial Refunded', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
   'public'                    => false,                                 
   'exclude_from_search'       => false,                                 
   'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,                                 
   'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,                                 
   'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Partial Refunded <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Partial Refunded <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' ),                              
   );      
   return $order_statuses;
}
```

2. Show Order Status in the Dropdown @ Single Order and "Bulk Actions" @ Orders

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_order_status' );


function custom_order_status( $order_statuses ) {      
   $order_statuses['wc-partialRefunded'] = _x( 'Partial Refunded', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );       
   return $order_statuses;
}
```

Many Thanks,
Sajidul

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used to create a custom order status called "Invoiced". Add this to your theme's functions.php

// New order status AFTER woo 2.2

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_new_order_statuses' );

function register_my_new_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-invoiced', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Invoiced', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Invoiced <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Invoiced<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'my_new_wc_order_statuses' );

// Register in wc_order_statuses.
function my_new_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-invoiced'] = _x( 'Invoiced', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );

    return $order_statuses;
}
```

source from :https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199295

Comment: thanks, @Ruban S
I need to update the order status only for the Partial refund.

Comment: As you can see here, the use of jQuery is not necessary at all https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-set-custom-order-status-for-new-orders/ @sajidulislam in this example, the status of the order is adjusted when ordering, but is it your intention to do this afterwards?

Comment: @L7c1f3r  Yes, I want something like that. As you can see [link](http://prntscr.com/r01h12) the product is partially refunded and still, the order status is **processing**. I want to switch this status automatically only for the partially refunded order. 

Actually, I need to count the partial order quantity too with this.

Comment: @L7c1f3r did you check the payment gateway supports automatic refunds..